# jquery-ui.js:12443 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have written this code in my project and it is displaying the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

```html
if (TempData["notice"] != null)
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <p id="dialog" style="color:red">
        @TempData["notice"]<br />
        <button id="bclose">Ok</button>
    </p>
    <script language="javascript">
        $('#dialog').dialog({
          dialogClass: "no-close",
          buttons: [{
            text: "Ok",
            Click: function() {
              $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            }
          }]
        });
    </script>
}
```

DO I need to add any library for the above code

Answer (score 0):

Put your script section into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your script here
});
```

Something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#dialog').dialog({
       dialogClass: "no-close",
       buttons: [{
         text: "Ok",
         click: function() {
           $('#dialog').dialog('close');
         }
       }]
     });
   });
</script>
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u06byuef/)

Comment: @AddadaSatish, change `Click` to `click`

Comment: When I am using $(document).ready(function(){
    //your script here
}); it was not showing anything and changed Click to click as wel

Comment: Did you try to change `Click` to `click` ?

Comment: Yes i haved it and Now the error is as follows Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at HTMLParagraphElement.click

Comment: @AddadaSatish, I have updated my answer with a working jsfiddle.

Comment: Still i Couldn't get the result for my application but its working in jsfiddle

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at HTMLParagraphElement.click (http://localhost:52025/LoggedIn/LoggedIn:45:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:12443:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:5226:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:4878:28)

Comment: Did you included twice jquery on page?

Comment: I have installed Jquery 1.10.2 through .net framework and have included the scirpt  which is of higher version(1.12.4) and if I include $(document).ready(function(){ }); its not working

Comment: Let's continue to this room : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128154/jquery-dialog

Comment: i don't have enough reputation (as per stackoverflow) to chat with you there in the above link

Comment: PageLoaders.js:325 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:52025/scripts/PageLoaders.js:325:18)
    at fire (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js:3119:30)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js:3231:7)
    at Function.ready (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js:3443:13)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js:3474:10)

Comment: Not here, in your post please include full page code,not errors